# typescript deduce output from input not working with generic

Tags: typescript

While working on better understanding typescript conditional typing I did hit a puzzle: i've got it working for specified type but not conditional type.

I known what i want to do can be achieved with overloading, but the new typescript tool `infer` and conditional typings allow us to be more generic in our type definitions and therefor not to repeat ourself that much. The following examples, cause simplified can be better expressed as overloads, but when it got more complicate it might not be the case.

Any how, on the principles i do not understand the error i made; here are the two examples:
First the types used

```
type In<T> = T | T[]
type Out<Type, T> = Type extends T ? T : T[]
```

Then for the specified (working) example:

```
// No generic version 'string' is passed directly
const foo = <Type extends In<string>>(
  x: Type,
): Out<Type, string> => x as any

const a = foo ('abc')             // string as expected
const b = foo (['abc', 'def'])    // string[] as expected
```

And finally the generic (non working) example

```
// Generic version type should? be inferred
const bar = <T, Type extends In<T>>(
  x: Type,
): Out<Type, T> => x as any


const c = bar ('abc')             // {} -> Error expected string
const d = bar (['abc', 'def'])    // {} -> Error expected string[]
```

Might be trivial but i can't find what i'm doing wrong :/

Thanks in advance
Seb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question (and please clarify if I do, so I can still help you), but wouldn't this simply work?

```
function bar<T extends number>(x: T): number
function bar<T extends string>(x: T): string
function bar<T extends any>(x: T): T
function bar<T>(x: T): T {
  return null;
}

const c = bar('abc')             //string
const d = bar(['abc', 'def'])    //string[]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, i did edit my original post - hopefully it will get more clear - since i'm still learning i do have issue pointing the case were a conditional approach will be better that stating all overloads (besides writing less boilerplate code) but i'm pretty sure when you talk of higher kind type that start to be adressable in typescript it will be necessary. I'm trying to understand to go through my way of understanding those complex typings, and i'm blocked in that case by typing not being able to infer a conditional when generic.

Comment: One possible use case is in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53228549/typescript-extends-like-for-return-type-how-to