# typescript extends-like for return type - how to?

Tags: typescript

Let's say we do have an object of type `X` implementing the `Iterable` interface containing number (such as `X extends Iterable<number>`).
I want to write a function, that we'll call `transformer` that will be able to produce a new object of type `X` *but* that could be this time written as `X extends Iterable<string>`.

A simple approach could be something like this:

```
const transformer = <X extends Iterable<number>(
  x: Type,
): Iterable<string> => null // produce an Iterable of strings
```

But doing so I loose the informations of X :/
If for instance I pass to transformer:

```
const t = transformer (new Set ([1, 2])) // transforme Set<number> to Iterable <string>
```

What i get is the iterable, but i won't be able to use the `Set` feature of t.

How can i tackle that issue? How can i say the compiler that the returns type of transformer is not an `Iterable<string>` but (in that example) a `Set<string>` ?

```
const transformer = <X extends Iterable<number>(
  x: Type,
)/*: X extends Iterable<string>*/ => null // transforme source<number> to source <string>
```

I can not use the extends in the returns type - is they're a way to tackle my issue without having to overloads the transformer for every `Iterable` that will be usable ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want [functors](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor) but since TypeScript doesn't support such [higher kinded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), all you can really do is work around it.  Hardcoding all usable transformer types is certainly one way to do it.

Comment: How do you implement the transformer, though?  Does it hardcode a list of things it can transform?  If so, then you can do it with conditional types... but that's not much different from overloads.

Comment: I've red the post your referencing, but in the end they show ways how to tackle this - just a tad complicated for me at the moment - implementation wise -
one way is to go run the iterator whrough next, and adds those values in an `array`, then do `new (x.constructor as any) (array)`